# Add multiple RNG columns to a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
db %>%
  add_column(X1 = rnorm(nrow(db),0,sample(SD,1)),
             X2 = rnorm(nrow(db),0,sample(SD,1))
             )
```

I would like to automatically generate 100 random columns. I want to keep each sampled `sd` a different draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You can use the [`dplyover`](https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/) package.
An exemple with `mtcars` as `db` and 10 different SD:

```
library(tidyverse)

db <- as_tibble(mtcars)
SD <- 1:10
n_col <- 100

sds <- sample(SD, n_col, replace = TRUE)
names(sds) <- paste0("X", seq_len(n_col))

mutate(db, dplyover::over(sds, ~ rnorm(n(), sd = .x)))
```

2 - Alternatively, you can create the random generated matrix separately and bind with `db` after

```
mat_rng <- as_tibble(lapply(sds, \(x) rnorm(nrow(db), sd = x)))
# or, as well suggested by @Adam
# mat_rng <- map_dfc(sds, rnorm, n = nrow(db), mean = 0)

bind_cols(db, mat_rng)
```

(works only with R >= 4.0.0 because I used the new anonymous function syntax)

Comment: `map_dfc()` from `purrr` would streamline your second approach a bit, which would be the one I would do.